# Excel Reverse recursive(?) Search

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a hierarchy in an Excel spreadsheet.

I've been  need a formula to return the UUID of the parent.  The parent is not always the cell above, neither are the hierarchy identifiers always decreasing.  The offspring are always beneath their 'parent'.

My data looks as below and the 'ParentId' column is what I'd like to get to.

| UUID | Hierarchy Ids | Hierarchy | ParentId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 961 | 1 | Granma Mavis |  |
| 974 | 2 | Mother Mary | 961 |
| 987 | 3 | Child Chastity | 974 |
| 1000 | 4 | Baby Blue | 987 |
| 1013 | 4 | Baby Bjorn | 987 |
| 1026 | 4 | Baby Annabell | 987 |
| 1039 | 4 | Baby Maybe | 987 |
| 1052 | 3 | Child Sarah | 974 |
| 1065 | 2 | Mother Moira | 961 |
| 1078 | 3 | Child Claire | 1065 |
| 1091 | 4 | Baby Bo | 1078 |
| 1104 | 3 | Child Sally | 1065 |
| 1117 | 1 | Grandpa Joe |  |
| 1130 | 2 | Father Gerald | 1117 |
| 1143 | 3 | Child Orson | 1130 |
| 1156 | 2 | Father Darren | 1117 |
| 1169 | 3 | Child Mylo | 1156 |

I've tried formulas including XLOOKUP, a bunch of nested ifs (doomed), VLOOKUP and LAMDA.

VLOOKUP was close (but no cigar) as it'd only ever return the *first* parentid - meaning that all Children would have the same parent (a very busy person!).

Comment: Just for fun, another alternative: `=IF(B2-1,MAXIFS(A$1:A1,B$1:B1,B2-1),"")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using an XLOOKUP formula. Formula in cell E2 (to be copied down) :

`=XLOOKUP(B2-1,$B$1:B1,$A$1:A1,"",0,-1)`

*Assumption:* Parent will be the one who is first case found from bottom to top search.

[image]

Comment: You concept is same as me but used different formula. It is good to solve by single formula. ^ from me.

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following formula-

```
=TAKE(FILTER($A$2:$A2,$B$2:$B2<B3,""),-1)
```

[image]

Comment: My only issue with this is that if I start the formula on F2, it gives erroneous results.  However, I truly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can judge, this can be done using a `VLookup()`, like in the example, based on this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(E4,B$3:E$19,3,FALSE)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: OP is expecting `E Column` as result.

Comment: @Harun24hr: does this even make sense? Every person has two parents, so Mother Mary should have both 961 (Gramma Mavis) **and** 1117 (Grandpa Joe) as parent IDs.

Comment: Thanks @Dominique, I played with the formula a little and got it to work.
=VLOOKUP(D2,A$2:D$18,1,FALSE)

The data included is a manipulation for ease of understanding, the actual data is an export of source data that I need to import into a different application.  The source and target systems record hierarchy differently.  Your (and all of the other posters) input have truly helped immensely.